# How can I fix the OpenCV error 'CAP_IMAGES: Can't find the starting number' when reading an rtsp stream in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, rtsp

I'm using opencv-python (version 4.7.0) python version 3.10.10 to capture my IP Camera (HikVision) stream.
which is connected using an ethernet cable. However I run into the challenge were the code run in debug mode by running the command python .py. However when I place a shortcut in a startup shortcut folder so that it runs on startup. The streaming function fails with the error below

```
[ERROR: 0@90.973] global cap.cpp:166 cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception
OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp: 253: error: (-5: Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: Can't find the starting number (in the name of file): rtsp://admin: xxxx@xxxxxxxx:554/Streaming/Channels/101/ in the function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'
```

Here is my code below and I use the function grabImage()

```
class VideoStreamWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, src='rtsp://admin:xxxxxx@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:554/Streaming/Channels/101/',valve=cv2.CAP_FFMPEG):
        # Create a VideoCapture object
        # Error in the line below
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)

        print(valve)
        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()
        print("Thread started")
        
    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()

    def show_frame(self):
        # Display frames in main program
        if self.status:
            self.frame = self.maintain_aspect_ratio_resize(self.frame, width=600)
            cv2.imshow('IP Camera Video Streaming', self.frame)

        # Press Q on keyboard to stop recording
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            self.capture.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            exit(1)
        
        if key%256 == 27:
            # ESC pressed
            print("Escape hit, closing...")
            #break

        img_counter = 0   
        if key%256 == 32:
            # SPACE pressed
            img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
            cv2.imwrite(img_name, self.frame)
            print("{} written!".format(img_name))
            img_counter += 1

    def grabImage(self, image_name = 'Image'):
         
        # time_diff = (self.end_time - datetime.now())
        
        
        # frame_time = 1000*time_diff.total_seconds()#round(1000*time_diff.total_seconds()/0)*40
        # print('frame_time',frame_time)
        
        if self.status:
            cv2.imwrite("files/image/staging/"+image_name+".jpg", self.frame)     # save frame as JPEG file
        else:
            print('No images is collected on the frame') 

    # Resizes a image and maintains aspect ratio
    def maintain_aspect_ratio_resize(self, image, width=None, height=None, inter=cv2.INTER_AREA):
        # Grab the image size and initialize dimensions
        dim = None
        (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

        # Return original image if no need to resize
        if width is None and height is None:
            return image

        # We are resizing height if width is none
        if width is None:
            # Calculate the ratio of the height and construct the dimensions
            r = height / float(h)
            dim = (int(w * r), height)
        # We are resizing width if height is none
        else:
            # Calculate the ratio of the 0idth and construct the dimensions
            r = width / float(w)
            dim = (width, int(h * r))

        # Return the resized image
        return cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=inter)
```

Below is build information of opencv

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.7.0 =====================================
  Version control:               4.7.0

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2023-02-22T13:19:52Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.17763 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.24.2
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 14 2015
    CMake build tool:            MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1900
    Configuration:               Debug Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (16 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (32 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe  (ver 19.0.24245.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /wd4819 /MP  /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /wd4819 /MP  /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP   /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /INCREMENTAL:NO  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrtd.lib
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /debug /INCREMENTAL  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          wsock32 comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32
    3rdparty dependencies:       libprotobuf ade ittnotify libjpeg-turbo libwebp libpng libtiff libopenjp2 IlmImf zlib quirc ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo python3 stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java python2 ts
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI:                           WIN32UI
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O:
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.13)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.3-62)
      SIMD Support Request:      YES
      SIMD Support:              NO
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      YES

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
    Include path:                D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.7.9/x64/python.exe (ver 3.7.9)
    Libraries:                   C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.7.9/x64/libs/python37.lib (ver 3.7.9)
    numpy:                       C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.7.9/x64/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.17.0)
    install path:                python/cv2/python-3

  Python (for build):            C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/python2.7.exe

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/8.0.362-9/x64/include C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/8.0.362-9/x64/include/win32 C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/8.0.362-9/x64/include
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.7/cmake-install
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried changing the priviledges of the shortcut for the py file to administrator level and restarted the application multiple times. Yet still have the same issue. I have also tried checking the physical ethernet cable  and confirmed it works well at streaming via rtsp using vlc for testing.

Comment: `print(cv.getBuildInformation())`

Comment: Please review question for the build information

Comment: your opencv build does not have gstreamer. that might be required for RTSP. apparently, no other backend feels responsible for the RTSP URL you passed. CAP_IMAGES is always tested last, and the last one's error is reported. -- if you pass CAP_FFMPEG as `apiPreference` to VideoCapture, this trial-and-error does not happen and you'd either get ffmpeg doing the job, or complaining. what's the meaning of "valve", why is that variable called that? why is it not used?

Comment: valve in this case is the apiPreference to VideoCapture however. I do not understand why its failing still even after using cv2.CAP_FFMPEG as the api reference?

Comment: how is it failing?

Comment: So I was thinking to my self.i had deployed similar systems and it work without issue. I believe its the opencv version that might be giving this issue.